# how to make onclick work for a different page and not only same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

So I got it to work that my accordion opens with a hyperlink when it's on the same page, but I am not successful yet in opening an accordion when it's linked to another page.
So instead
`<a href="#test" onclick='$("#test").click()'>TEST</a>` 
I want: `<a href="somewebsite.com#test" onclick='$("somewebsite.com#test").click()'>TEST</a>`

But it won't open when I link it to a different page! Can someone please enlighten me?

```js
 $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $this = $(this);

                if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) { 
                    $this.next().removeClass('show');
                    $this.next().slideUp(350);
                } else {
                    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
                    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
                    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
                    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
                }
            });
```

```css
 .toggle{
                margin-left:0px;
            }
            ul.accordion {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin:0;

            }


            ul.accordion .inner {
                padding-left: 50px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: none;
            }


            ul.accordion li {
                margin: .5em 0;
                font-weight: 300;
            }

            ul.accordion li a.toggle {

                display: block;
                background: rgba(0,114,178, 1);
                color: #fefefe;
                padding: .75em;
                padding-left: 50px;
                border-radius: 0.4em;
                transition: background .3s ease;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            ul li a.toggle:hover {
                background: rgba(0,114,178, 0.75);

            }
            .centerjustifiy {
                width:60%;

            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      

        <div class="centerjustify">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, <a href="#test" onclick='$("#test").click()'>TEST</a>pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.</p>
            <ul class="accordion">
                <li>
                    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>
                            <a  href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner</a>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                                    blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner #2</a>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>
                                    Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a id="test" class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="toggle">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
                            <ul class="inner">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Another nested element</a>
                                    <div class="inner">
                                        <p>
                                            As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                                            blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>Option 2</li>

                        <li>Option 3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>



        </div>
```

Comment: You can make a link to another page and you can even target a section of that page, but you can't register event handlers on the DOM of a different page. Once you get to that page, that page's code will execute and only that page's code can tell it what to do. Again, you can send messages to that other page, but not direct commands.

Comment: Why do you need both href and onclick? Can you just use href="somewebsite.com#test" and remove the onClick?

Comment: @user3115056 Because he wants to invoke the `.click()` method.

Comment: Each page is completely unique with regard to html and javascript.  You can pass information across in the url or via post/cookies/sessionstate/etc but you can't run javascript functions in the new page.   So pass in the url `somewebsite.com?test=1` and in the other page `if (location.href.contains("test=1")) $(".toggle").click();` - this of course assumes you have control over the other page and you're not trying to hack / spoof or have other *nefarious* purposes in mind.

Comment: @freedomn-m So I changed it to '<a href="somewebsite.com?test=1" onclick='$("somewebsite.com?test=1").click()'>TEST</a>' and I added 'if (location.href.contains("test=1")) $(".toggle").click();' to the other page (because yes I have control over it) but it still won't open unfortunately...